# Converting query parameter from String to integer

Tags: mybatis

I'm passing a HashMap

```
HashMap<String, String> paramsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
paramsMap.put("jobXXX", "" + jobState.getCode());
paramsMap.put("rmi_auftrag_xxx", "rmi_auftrag_status");
```

to a MyBatis query:

```
<select id="loadRmiOrdersByTypeOrState" parameterType="map" resultMap="rmiJobMap">
    <![CDATA[
      SELECT rmi_auftrag_id as rmiJobId,
             rmi_auftrag_typ as rmiJobType,
             rmi_auftrag_status as rmiJobState,
             rm_dokument_id as rmDocId
      FROM   lis_mgr.rmi_auftrag
      WHERE  #{rmi_auftrag_xxx} = #{jobXXX,javaType=String,jdbcType=NUMERIC}
      ]]>
</select>
```

The type of the jobXXX parameter is yet an integer. Is there a way to tell MyBatis to convert the integer-in-string-form into a "true" integer?

Answer (score 1):

You can put your Integer as Integer into your HashMap and then run the query.

```
HashMap<String, Object> paramsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
paramsMap.put("jobXXX", jobState.getCode());
paramsMap.put("rmi_auftrag_xxx", "rmi_auftrag_status");
```

Answer (score 0):

method 1).  user custom type handler

```
public class StringToIntTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<String> {

    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, String parameter, JdbcType jdbcType)  throws SQLException {
        ps.setString(i, Integer.valueOf(parameter));
    }
   //...
 }
```

xml

```
#{jobXXX,typeHandler=xxx.StringToIntTypeHandler}
```

method 2). use ognl

```
<bind name="param" value="@java.lang.Integer@valueOf(jobXXX)" />
  //...
 where  #{rmi_auftrag_xxx} = #{param}
```

or
    `${@java.lang.Integer@valueOf(jobXXX)}`